# How to stop a div in a column from going underneath another column with an iframe?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

On this page http://www.prllighting.com/, I have a Photoplus widget next to a video, (below the main banner) in separate bootstrap columns and I do not understand why when the page goes below 1200 pixels the widget goes underneath the iframe video. I put them both in DIVs and defined them like this:

```
<div class="photoplus"><script type='text/javascript.....</script></div>
<div class="productpage-video"><iframe width="640" height="360" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..."></iframe></div>

.photoplus {
display:inline-block;
width: 200px;
height:332px;
}

.productpage-video {
display:inline-block;
}
```

How do I edit it, so that they never overlap?

Answer (score 0):

Your "photoplus" class has fixed width of 200px and it should be percentage width. (100%)
And also inner content of it also should be adjustable width like 100%; 
And "productpage-video" inside this class, iframe has fixed width. That one also should be 100%.

```
    .photoplus {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 332px;
        width: 100%;
    }

   .photoplus iframe {
       width: 100% !important;
   }

    .productpage-video iframe {
       width: 100% !important;
    }
```

But anyway when small sizes (for mobile sizes), better to move the video to second line.

Comment: thanks for the response but this didn't fix the problem.  the problem was when you resize the browser below 1200 px the photoplus widget still goes partially beneath the video.  It's actually worse.  Why does one div/column go underneath the other?